# how to lookup a value based first 4 characters of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to lookup a value based on the first 4 characters of a cell. I'm using the below formula but it returns an error.

What am I doing wrong?

`=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,4),COUNTRIES!B:C,2,FALSE)`

Comment: First 3 values or 4 values?

Comment: `values` or `characters`?

Comment: @AndyG first 4 values

Comment: @ScottCraner characters

Comment: By error do you mean it returns #N/A?

Comment: What error do you have? #N/A just means that there's no entry with those four letters in your "Countries" B-column. By the way, why do you countries only contain 4 letters?

Comment: Try: `=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,4) & "*",COUNTRIES!B:C,2,FALSE)`

Comment: @aab your formula works for me, make sure that the value appears in the range you specify.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an #N/A error, that just means that the lookup function can't find anything that matches your search string exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Left transform the value into text in that function. Force it back

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(A2,4)),COUNTRIES!B:C,2,FALSE)
```